# Can the masterKey be used in an iOS App to send Push Notifications with Parse Server?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to develop a `Push Notifications` feature in an app by first trying to send them through the app, which I've heard `masterKey` is required for. Although I haven't heard of anywhere I can put the `masterKey` into my Xcode project.

Is there a specific location to include the `masterKey` in my Xcode project? Can masterKey even be used in a swift project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, masterKey must be used to send push notification but Parse-server is not going to support pushing from client apps due to security issues. So, you need to write a cloud function for it. A simple cloud function that send pushes to all users who have installed your app looks like this.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("push", function(request, response){
    var message = request.params.message;
    //Pushes work with Installation table
    //So, you need to select to whom you want to push
    var installationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);

    //You should set expiration time when push will be expired
    //This is optional
    var expDate = new Date();
    expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate() + 1); //The notification will expire in 1 day

    //Setting up push data
    var data = {"badge": "Increment", "sound": "default"};
    data['alert'] = message;

    //Sending push
    Parse.Push.send({
        where: installationQuery,
        data: data,
        expiration_time: expDate
    },{
        success: function () {
            response.success("Pushed successfully");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error(error);
        },
        useMasterKey: true
    });
});
```

In your iOS app,

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("push", withParameters: ["message":"Pushing from cloud code"]) {
  (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  //Do stuffs
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

masterKey is added server side. depending on your setup or instance you can set it up in your `index.js` file.

```
// With the value of your app's Master Key completed:
masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '<your app's Master Key>'
```

If you are using environmental variables you can set your `json` file with this value:

```
"PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY": "#####",
```

Should be in the same file where you set the paths to the certificates.